# Python beautiful soup web scraper doesn't return tag contents

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'am trying to scrape matches and their respective odds from local bookie site but every site i try my web **scraper** doesn't return anything rather  just prints "Process finished with exit code 0" but doesn't return anything.
Can someone help me crack open the containers and get out the contents.

i have tried all the above sites for almost a month but with no success. The problem seems to be with the exact div, class or probably span element layout.

1. https://www.betlion.co.ug/
2. https://www.betpawa.ug/
3. https://www.premierbet.ug/

for example i tried link 2 in the code as shown

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.betpawa.ug/"

response = requests.get (url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup (response.content, "html.parser")

for match in content.findAll("div",attrs={"class":"events-container prematch", "id":"Bp-Event-591531"}):
    print (match.text.strip())
```

i expect the program to return a list of matches, odds and all the other components of the container. however the program runs and just prints " "Process finished with exit code 0" nothing else

Comment: FYI it’s __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scrape__, __scraped__) not scrapper.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the base site gets loaded in two phases

1. Load some HTML structure for the page,
2. Use JavaScript to fill in the contents

You can prove this to yourself by right clicking on the page, do "view page source" and then searching for "events-container" (it is not there).

So you'll need something more powerful than requests + bs4.  I have heard of folks using Selenium to do this, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: let me post the html layout

Comment: <div class="events-container prematch" id="Bp-Event-594286">

Comment: thanks chris i will be left with the selenium option indeed coz  i've tried this for too long now

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `urllib3` instead of `requests`.
`from urllib.request import Request, urlopen`.
- build your req: 
`req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})`

- retrieve document:
`res = urlopen(req)`

- parse it using `bs4`:
`html = BeautifulSoup (res, 'html.parser')`

Comment: how would i incorporate the for statement to pull out all the matches?. Thanks

Comment: I have tried urlib and beautiful soup but i still get the "Process finished with exit code 0" return only.     from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.betway.ug/"

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

res = urlopen(req)

content = BeautifulSoup (res, 'html.parser')


for match in content.findAll ('div', attrs={"class": "events-container prematch","id":"Bp-Event-591570"}):
    print (match.text.strip())

Answer (score 0):

Like Chris Curvey described, the problem is that requests can't execute the JavaScript of the page. If you print your content variable you can see that the page would display a message like: "JavaScript Required! To provide you with the best possible product, our website requires JavaScript to function..." With Selenium you control an full browser in form of an WebDriver (for eample ChromeDriver binary for the Google Chrome Browser):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options) 

url = "https://www.betpawa.ug/"
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source
content = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
for match in content.findAll("div",attrs={"class":"events-container"}):
    print (match.text.strip())
```

## Update:

In Line 13 the command print (match.text.strip()) simply extract only the text elements for each match-div's wich has the class-attribute "events-container".
If you want to extract more specific content you can access each match over the match variable.
You need to know:

- which of the avabile information you want
- and how to indentify this information inside the match-div's
  structure.
- in which data-type you need this information

To make it easy run the program, open the developer tools of chrome with key F12, on the left top corner you see now the icon for "select an element ...", 
if you click on the icon and click in the browser on the desired element you see in the area under the icon the equivalent source.
Analyse it carefully to get the info's you need, for example:

1. The Title of the Football match is the first h3-Tag in the match-div
   and is an string
2. The Odd's shown are span-tag's with the class event-odds and an
   number (float/double)

Search the function you need in Google or in the reference to the package you use (BeautifulSoup4).
Let's try to get it **quick and dirty** by using the BeautifulSoup functions on the match variable to don't get the elements of the full site (have replaced the whitespace with tabs):

```
# (1) lets try to find the h3-tag
title_tags = match.findAll("h3") # use on match variable
if len(title_tags) > 0: # at least one found?
    title = title_tags[0].getText()  # get the text of the first one
    print("Title: ", title) # show it
else:
    print("no h3-tags found")
    exit()
# (2) lets try to get some odds as numbers in the order in which they are displayed
odds_tags = match.findAll("span", attrs={"class":"event-odds"})
if len(odds_tags) > 2: # at least three found?
    odds = [] # create an list
    for tag in odds_tags:   # loop over the odds_tags we found
        odd = tag.getText() # get the text
        print("Odd: ", odd)
        # good but it is an string, you can't compare it with an number in
        # python and expect an good result.
        # You have to clean it and convert it: 
        clean_odd = odd.strip() # remove empty spaces
        odd = float(clean_odd)  # convert it to float
        print("Odd as Number:", odd)
else:
    print("something wen't wrong with the odds")
    exit()
input("Press enter to try it on the next match!")
```

Comment: Thanx ClydeZ, its opening up the web page well and i can see the matches like i normally would using a browser. however, i still don't know how to extract the matches and their respective odds into data that i can manipulate. Any clues?